# Организация вывода фраз из бд на html страницу по рейтингу и случайно

Tags: php, fat-free

Уважаемые профессионалы.

Как правильно изменить (дописать) код чтобы получился вывод из БД на html страницу:

1. По рейтингу
2. Случайный вывод

-

```
F3::route('GET /',
function () {
    F3::set('html_title','Название');
    include  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/perecc/rating/rating.php';
    //$article=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM article ORDER by id DESC limit 5');

    $rep_page=100;
    $num_pages=ceil(paginator()/$rep_page);
    for($i=1;$i<=$num_pages;$i++){
    $pages[$i][0]=$i;
    }

    F3::set('paginator',$pages);
    $query="SELECT * FROM article ORDER by id DESC limit $rep_page";
    $article=mysql_query($query) or die ("Error");

    $query2="SELECT content FROM article";
    $randmas=mysql_query($query2);
    for ($randmasdata=array();$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($randmas);$randmasdata[]=$row);
    for ($data=array();$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($article);$data[]=$row);
    $rnd=rand(1, count($randmasdata)-1);
    $random[0]=$randmasdata[$rnd];

    F3::set('content','blog_home.html');
    for ($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
    $data[$i]['rat']=callrating($data[$i]['id'], "thumb", '&nbsp;');
    }

    F3::set('random',$random);
    F3::set('list',$data);
    echo Template::serve('layout.html');    
}
);
```

**Перенесено из комментария.**

Может как-то так?

```
<?php

@mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("kakaeto_bd");
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$col = 1; // Сколько всего выводить записей

$sql = "SELECT * FROM anekdots ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT " . $col;
$res = mysql_query($sql);

for ($i = 0; $i < $col; $i++) {
    $row    = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $text   = $row['text'];
    $author = $row['author'];
    echo $text . " [ Автор:<b>" . $author . "</b> ]";
}

?>
```

Comment: У меня только одно предложение: выкинуть этот код и написать нормально.

З.Ы. F3 не знаю, поэтому подробней не отвечу..  Но код отвратительный

Comment: Помогите сделать на php.
Буду благодарен кто поможет сделать, как надо... Мои контакты: vesbiznes@mail.ru

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.